# Why time and space complexity of counting sort is O(n + k) and not O(max(n, k))?

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity, radix-sort, counting-sort

Here, 'n' and 'k' are the size of the input array and the maximum element of the array respectively.

Since there is one run in the array of size 'n' for the count of the frequency of elements and, a separate run in the array of size 'k' and for each pass(or iteration) in the array, there are count[i] iterations where 'count' is the array of size 'k'.

Same with space complexity.

I am looking for a good explanation explaining every bit of the concept, as you can guess I am horribly confused.

Comment: Big O represents the worst case. Loop is running near about  (n+k) times which is greater than max(n,k).

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `O(n+k) = O(max(n, k))` because

```
       max(n,k) <= n+k <= 2max(n,k)
```

and the big-O doesn't see the constant `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who has responded. But, I think I got it.

Assumptions:

- Actual array with size `N` is `A[]`
- Maximum element in array `A[]` is `K`
- Array for counting frequency of elments with size `K` is `count[]`
- Auxiliary array for storing sorted elements with size `N` is `sorted[]`

I looked at it in this way, there is one run in `A[]` for getting the maximum element and one more run to store the frequency of each element.
This takes `O(N)`.

Now, there is one run in `count[]` and for each iteration, there is a loop for `count[i]` times for inserting the array elements in the sorted order in `sorted[]`.
The sum of all the elements in `count[]` cannot be greater than `N`. So the total time for these operations is `O(N + K)`

Therefore, the worst-case time complexity is `O(N + K)`. Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two runs on the array `k`

The `k` represents the size of the array. The 'k' in O notation actually represent the maximum element.

If we write O(max(n,k)) it will hide the details of the algorithm, which is highly dependent on the maximum element